# Overlaping raw thermal image and embedded image from FLIR

Tags: opencv, image-processing, flir

I have two images: a thermal image from FLIR e an embedded image which I extract from the metadata embedded in the thermal image. Example:

[image: Thermal Image]

[image]

All metadata available in the thermal image are:

```
File Name: FLIR2721.jpg
File Size: 1000 kB
File Type: JPEG
File Type Extension: jpg
Mime Type: image/jpeg
Jfif Version: 1.01
Exif Byte Order: Little-endian (Intel, II)
Make: FLIR Systems AB
Model: FLIR T620
Orientation: Horizontal (normal)
X Resolution: 72
Y Resolution: 72
Resolution Unit: inches
Software: 4.8.2
Modify Date: 2017:11:29 08:34:08
Y Cb Cr Positioning: Centered
Exposure Time: 1/46
Exif Version: 220
Create Date: 2017:11:29 08:34:08
Components Configuration: -, Cr, Cb, Y
Subject Distance: 1 m
Focal Length: 41.3 mm
Image Temperature Max: 332
Image Temperature Min: 235
Flashpix Version: 100
Color Spaces: RGB
Exif Image Width: 640
Exif Image Height: 480
Digital Zoom Ratio: 1
Image Unique Id: DF9BB2EBB15922366AB9059A1D8D53A9
Gps Version Id: 2.2.0.0
Gps Altitude Ref: Above Sea Level
Gps Time Stamp: 11:48:03
Gps Satellites: 0
Gps Img Direction Ref: Magnetic North
Gps Img Direction: 160
Compression: JPEG (old-style)
Thumbnail Offset: 2172
Thumbnail Length: 5973
Emissivity: 0.75
Object Distance: 1.00 m
Reflected Apparent Temperature: 20.0 C
Atmospheric Temperature: 28.0 C
Ir Window Temperature: 20.0 C
Ir Window Transmission: 1
Relative Humidity: 60.0 %
Planck R: 115965.437
Planck B: 1417.1
Planck F: 1
Atmospheric Trans Alpha1: 0.006569
Atmospheric Trans Alpha2: 0.01262
Atmospheric Trans Beta1: -0.002276
Atmospheric Trans Beta2: -0.00667
Atmospheric Trans X: 1.9
Camera Temperature Range Max: 150.0 C
Camera Temperature Range Min: -40.0 C
Camera Temperature Max Clip: 160.0 C
Camera Temperature Min Clip: -60.0 C
Camera Temperature Max Warn: 150.0 C
Camera Temperature Min Warn: -40.0 C
Camera Temperature Max Saturated: 180.0 C
Camera Temperature Min Saturated: -60.0 C
Camera Model: FLIR T620
Camera Part Number: 55903-5022 
Camera Serial Number: 55906523
Camera Software: 25.0.0
Lens Model: FOL41
Lens Part Number: T197524
Lens Serial Number: 56702775
Field Of View: 15.0 deg
Planck O: -3949
Planck R: 20.01401533
Raw Value Range Min: 5427
Raw Value Range Max: 56178
Raw Value Median: 13350
Raw Value Range: 10060
Date Time Original: 2017:11:29 08:34:08.131+00:00
Focus Step Count: 5925
Focus Distance: 8.9 m
Frame Rate: 30
Palette Colors: 224
Above Color: 170 128 128
Below Color: 50 128 128
Overflow Color: 67 216 98
Underflow Color: 41 110 240
Isotherm1 Color: 100 128 128
Isotherm2 Color: 100 110 240
Palette Method: 0
Palette Stretch: 2
Palette File Name: \FlashBFS\system\iron.pal
Palette Name: Iron
Palette: (Binary data 672 bytes)
Raw Thermal Image Width: 640
Raw Thermal Image Height: 480
Raw Thermal Image Type: PNG
Raw Thermal Image: (Binary data 362104 bytes)
Real2 Ir: 3.7806735038757
Offset X: -35
Offset Y: -131
Pi Px1: 160
Pi Px2: 479
Pi Py1: 120
Pi Py2: 359
Gps Valid: Yes
Gps Latitude Ref: South
Gps Longitude Ref: West
Gpsdop: 0.53
Gps Map Datum: WGS84
Embedded Image Width: 2592
Embedded Image Height: 1944
Embedded Image Type: JPG
Embedded Image: (Binary data 600954 bytes)
Image Width: 640
Image Height: 480
Encoding Process: Baseline DCT, Huffman coding
Bits Per Sample: 8
Color Components: 3
Y Cb Cr Sub Sampling: YCbCr4:2:0 (2 2)
Gps Altitude: 0 m Above Sea Level
Gps Latitude: 26 deg 18' 1.14" S
Gps Longitude: 48 deg 51' 2.82" W
Gps Position: 26 deg 18' 1.14" S, 48 deg 51' 2.82" W
Image Size: 640x480
Megapixels: 0.307
Peak Spectral Sensitivity: 10.2 um
Shutter Speed: 1/46
Thumbnail Image: (Binary data 5973 bytes)
Focal Length35Efl: 41.3 mm
Category: image
Raw Header: FF D8 FF E0 00 10 4A 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 FF E1 1F BC 45 78 69 66 00 00 49 49 2A 00 08 00 00 00 0B 00 0F 01 02 00 10 00 00 00 92 00 00 00 10 01 02 00 0A 00 00 00 A2 00 00 00
```

I want to "overlap" the thermal image in the embedded image but I don't know how to do this since the thermal image is not centered with the embedded image.

I've tried to use [matchTemplate](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/df/dfb/group__imgproc__object.html#ga586ebfb0a7fb604b35a23d85391329be) form OpenCV but the result is not quite good.

Any suggestions about how to solve it?

Comment: Have you tried applying some border filtering like sobel o laplacian on both images before template matching? Also, have you tried different methods for template matching?

Comment: So you want the coordinates of 2 part of images same for both images? What is the relation of this problem with ```matchTemplate```?

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk I tried ```matchTemplate for finding the coordinates on the embedded image which corresponds the thermal image```. Basically I tried to find the rectangle on the embedded images which would give me the thermal image.

Comment: @alan.elkin I just tried ```matchTemplate``` itself. I was thinking about solving this using the metadata from thermal image instead of applying filtering algorithms

Comment: This problem about calibration of those 2 cameras. Matchtemplate has no relation with this problem. 2 camera in different location thats the problem. you should calibrate them

Comment: Is there any sort of zoom applied here? I tried some cropping of the image with those metadata values but could not  find the exact same crop of the rgb image. Any other information?

Comment: @Yunus Temurlenk this seems to be the same image with different spectral ranges but taken from the same camera, one being a crop of the other but with IR instead of RGB

Comment: @alan.elkin Indeed, it is. The problem is to get the smaller image in the bigger image.

Answer (score 0):

I think here is all data you need:

```
Raw Thermal Image Width: 640
Raw Thermal Image Height: 480
Raw Thermal Image Type: PNG
Raw Thermal Image: (Binary data 362104 bytes)
Real2 Ir: 3.7806735038757
Offset X: -35
Offset Y: -131
```

`Real2 Ir` value looks like zoom ratio of raw IR image to JPEG photo. 640x480*3.7806735038757=2420x1815 which is very close to 2592x1944. So you just need to test some combinations of what `Pi Px/y` coordinates and `Offset X/Y` means. Enlarge IR image (or reduce JPEG), center both images manually in graphics editor and check what X/Y distance between upper left corners of both images is. I think it will be same as some of these values.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution but have no ideia of why it works.

Sample code:

```
import math
import cv2

emb_img = cv2.imread(<path_to_embedded_image>, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

emb_height, emb_width, emb_channels = emb_img.shape
emb_center = {
    'x': math.floor(emb_width / 2),
    'y': math.floor(emb_height / 2)
}

raw_img = cv2.imread(<path_to_raw_image>, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

raw_height, raw_width = raw_img.shape
raw_center = {
    'x': math.floor(raw_width / 2),
    'y': math.floor(raw_height / 2)
}

j = {
    'OffsetX': <some number>,
    'OffsetY': <some number>
}

x = emb_center.get('x') - raw_center.get('x') + j.get('OffsetX') - 45
y = emb_center.get('y') - raw_center.get('y') + j.get('OffsetY') - 45

cropped_img = emb_img[y:y+540, x:x+720, :]

cropped_img = cv2.resize(cropped_img, (640, 480))

cv2.imwrite('path_you_want.jpg', cropped_img)
```

I have no ideia why to write `cropped_img = emb_img[y:y+540, x:x+720, :]` instead of `cropped_img = emb_img[y:y+480, x:x+680, :]` since raw size is 680x540. Another thing, `45` came from where??? I just know it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing with Photoshop and the embedded image, i believe this may work:

```
import cv2
import  flirimageextractor
flir = flirimageextractor.FlirImageExtractor()
flir.process_image('C:\Temp\FLIR14107.jpg',RGB=True)
c = flir.get_metadata('C:\Temp\FLIR1234.jpg')
img = flir.extract_embedded_image()
Scale = c['Real2IR']
OffsetX = c['OffsetX']
OffsetY = c['OffsetY']
PiPX1 = c['PiPX1']
PiPX2 = c['PiPX2']
PiPY1 = c['PiPY1']
PiPY2 = c['PiPY2']
Width = c['EmbeddedImageWidth']
Height = c['EmbeddedImageHeight']
scaled_img = cv2.resize(img.astype('uint8'), (int(Width * Scale), int(Height * 
                         Scale)), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

ct = [int(scaled_img.shape[1] / 2), int(scaled_img.shape[0] / 2)]
cx = ct[0] + OffsetX * Scale
cy = ct[1] + OffsetY * Scale
img1 = scaled_img[int(cy - Height/2):int(cy + Height/2),
              int(cx - Width/2):int(cx + Width/2)]
cv2.imshow('1',cv2.resize(img1,(PiPX1 + PiPX2,PiPY1 + 
PiPY2),interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA))
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked to see if astrophotography stacking software could help, or could be a pointer to a similar technology. Long exposure images of stars are rarely a single exposure, but consist of hundreds of images. Normally the software automatically detects key stars to help align the images, but maybe there is a way to choose key points on each image to tell the software how to carry out the alignment.